# How do I Cancel or Terminate a workflow from within itself

Tags: c#, workflow, workflow-foundation-4

I have a workflow that moves files around between ftp sites.
It can be the case that a user deletes the files from an ftp site while the workflow is about to copy it.  I can detect that the file is gone, so I want to Cancel the workflow about to do the file transfer.

I start my workflows using a factory.  The factory creates a helper class (wfManager) and the helper class starts the actual workflow using WorkflowApplication.

The workflow itself determines if it should Close based on if the file has gone missing.  The workflow has a reference to the wfManager that started it so calls workflowApplication.close from the wfManager

I had thought that if I use WorkflowApplication.close from the wfManager that the workflow would Close.

However, the Close times out.

What would cause the Close to time out and is there a generic way to close or terminate a workflow via code?

Comment: do you mean WorkflowInstance by "workflow" ? and from where do you want to terminate ? the Workflowinstance ? an Activity ?

Comment: I suppose it's an Instance of a Workflow.  It's the Workflow (instance) that is created with:  workflowApp = new WorkflowApplication(new actFtpWatcher(), inParams);

An Activity detects that the Instance should Close and then uses workflowApp.Close called from the class that created the workflow

Comment: please see my answer below and the MSDN links...

Comment: From what I can understand he wants to terminate the workflow from within a custom activity. Something that although possible to some extend is an indication that workflow logic is flawed. Check if file exists (with a custom activity that receives a filename and returns a boolean, for example) and go through different paths using *If* activity - do nothing and terminate if false, otherwise do its thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have basically 3 options to end a worklflow:

- `Cancel`
  As you have seen this waits a bit of time (so the workflow can finish whatever it is currently doing), then closes the workflow, then invoke the OnCompleted handler
- `Terminate`
  This takes a reason for termination (as a param), waits a bit of time (so the workflow can finish whatever it is currently doing), then closes the workflow, then invoke the OnCompleted handler
- `Abort`
  This just kills the workflow and does not call OnCompleted handler.

MSDN references:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd987846.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms611688.aspx

Comment: I think I know why the Cancel times out.  A code activity starts the process to Cancel.  I'm thinking that the Cancel operation is waiting for the code activity to complete while the code activity is waiting for Cancel to complete.  I effectively have a dead lock.  This seem a reasonable analysis?

Comment: @Richard210363 yes it does, esp. since WF 4 is more async than WF 3.5 was.

Answer (score 2):

In addition you can terminate your workflow from inside of the workflow using a TerminateWorkflow activity.

Also keep in mind that everything in WF4 is asynchronous and if the workflow is blocking in an activity the Cancel() call will time out because the scheduler will only do one action at the time.

Answer (score 2):

If a workflow decides it wants to cancel itself there are two options

1. Throw an unhandled exception - results in Workflow Aborted (eligible for resume)
2. Use the Terminate activity - results in Workflow Terminated (workflow completes)

In your scenario you should use the Terminate activity.

Trying to call back to other objects that attempt to cancel the workflow on a callback thread is a recipe for disaster (as you found out).  Likewise you cannot cancel the workflow from any delegate handler or extension.